# Splash Screen for iPhone and Android Web Browser

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, html, splash-screen

Want to display the splash page for iphone and android web browser. I am new to this. Whats the best way to do this? is there any tutorial ?

For iphone i want like a modal screen.

Thanks for all your help.

Best.

Comment: Why do you want to use a splash screen? They tend to hurt the user experience and annoy users. http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply .... I have the page with nothing on it .. Its dead. Just want to show them Please come back again and a button to redirect to the different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set some meta information on your html like :

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/img/startup-landscape.png" sizes="1024x748" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/img/startup-portrait.png" sizes="768x1004" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/img/startup-portrait.png" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
```